# Django QuerySet values_list returning unknown characters

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset

I am using django to pull some data from the MySQL server I have.  Currently I have it pulling a whole column of data (the "light" column) from the SQL server.

To do this I am using the following code

```
weather = weatherdata.objects.values_list('light', flat=True)

lightdata = list(weather)
```

When I do this the lightdata list looks like this:

```
[35L, 53L, 77L, 99L, 49L, 46L, 28L, 13L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L]
```

Those values are correct, its just there is an L at the end of each of these. How can I remove the L from this list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
l = [35L, 53L, 77L, 99L, 49L, 46L, 28L, 13L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L]
l = [int(item) for item in l]
```

Also if you want to delete the replicated items:

```
l = [35L, 53L, 77L, 99L, 49L, 46L, 28L, 13L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L]
l = list(set(l))
l = [int(item) for item in l]
```

Comment: just a comment. To remove replicated items may be better append a distinct() in query.

Answer (score 2):

The L at the end is indicative that it's a long type.  It won't print through a print statement, and it's just telling you that the number stored here is definitely not an integer.

If you really wanted to get rid of them, then I suppose you could do something like the following:

```
lightdataNew = []
for num in lightdata:
    lightdataNew.append(int(num))
lightdata = lightdataNew[:]
```

Answer (score 1):

The L indicates a long integer.

```
>>> a = long(5)
>>> a
5L
>>> print a
5
```

You could convert the type of the elements in the list depending on your needs but it may not be necessary.

```
>>> b = [int(i) for i in list_of_longs]
>>> c = [str(i) for i in list_of_longs]
```

Edit: Seems Goin, Makoto and I were all typing answers at the same time.